# Incorrect syntax near 's' in pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, json, sql-server, pyodbc

Sometimes I get this error randomly when I try to insert data in to the database. I fetch the data with using request.get and parsing the JSON data.

This is the error that I get:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17
>   for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 's'. (102)
>   (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL
>   Server][SQL Server]Unclosed quotation mark after the character string
>   ')'. (105)")

This is my code:

```
for product in parsed['products']:
                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dbo.producten (productid, datum_toegevoegd, naam, prijs_excl, prijs_incl, gewicht) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')" %(product['id'],product['created_at'], product['nl']['title'],product['price_excl'],product['price_incl'],product['weight']))
```

Comment: Try constructing the query string (without executing it) and printing it so you can see what is actually being passed to the SQL server. That way you can debug what is being added in the string.

Comment: Using string formatting `%` in sql is really really not recommended. This kind of thing opens up a whole class of security vulnerabilities called SQL injection. The database library should should provide a safe alternative to raw string formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must not use string interpolation for SQL queries. The db-api will do correct parameter substitution for you - replace that `%` with a comma.

```
cursor.execute('SELECT.... ', (product['id'],product['created_at'...))
#                           ^
```

Comment: They should use `?` as a placeholder in the format string. `cursor.execute("select a from tbl where b=? and c=?", x, y)`
https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Features-beyond-the-DB-API#passing-parameters

Comment: @HåkenLid I changed the format and now I get the following error, what am I missing here?

pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '='. (102) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")

Code is like this now:

 cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dbo.producten (productid, datum_toegevoegd, naam, prijs_excl, prijs_incl, gewicht) VALUES (productid=?,datum_toegevoegd=?,naam=?,prijs_excl=?,prijs_incl=?,gewicht=?)" ,(product['id']...etc

Comment: I don't think this new expression is valid SQL. You should not use `=` with `INSERT VALUES`. Just change `%s` in the original code to `?` (I'm not a sql expert, but I think you can drop the quotes as well `'%s'` -> `?`)

Comment: @HåkenLid yeah indeed you are correct, that solved the problem:)

Answer (score 1):

```
cursor.execute('SELECT.... product = ?', (value_for_product))
```

works for python 3.^